# How to remove a character from text using regex in notepad ++?

Tags: regex, string, replace, notepad++

I have a value in a CSV file like "xx"" where xx is any number. I want to replace it with "xx" using regex in notepad++.

For example:

```
"20"" to "20"
"4"" to "4"
```

I am able to find the value using `"20""` using `("[0-9][0-9]"")` but it doesn't get me `"4""`. 
Also, I need to replace it with only a single quote in the end instead of double quotes. ("4" or "04")

Comment: use this "[0-9]{0,2}""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex

Find

```
(?:("\d+")")
```

Replace

```
\1
```

Answer (score 1):

Find: `"(\d+)""`

Replace: `"\1"`

Or to limit to only 1 or 2 digits:

Find: `"(\d{1,2})""`

FYI `[0-9] == \d`

Comment: Thanks for the help. This one also removes the double quotes that I need. It transforms "04"" to 04 which is not my requirement.

Comment: It doesn't remove them, for clarity `"\1"` is literally what you put in the 'replace' box. You might have just put `\1` in there

Comment: Yeah, what if I want to change "04"" to 04". What will be the change in regex?

Comment: Ok I got it. I used "(\d+")"

Answer (score 1):

- **Find**: `("[0-9]+")"`
- **Replace**: `$1`